# Some question on real-valued function on matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

Let me ask you very general question and probably a stupid question: Suppose we have some real-valued function $f$ whose domain is $\text{Mat}_n(\mathbb{R})$ - the set of square matrices of order $n$ with real coefficient.

Take some matrix $A$ and let's consider the new matrices $A_1,\dots,A_n$ where $A_j$ is the matrix which is obtained from $A$ in the following way: we take first row of $A$ and change it by $j$th row of identity matrix of order $n$.

\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & \dots & 0 \\
a_{21} & a_{22} &\dots & a_{2n}\\
\dots \\
a_{n1} & a_{n2} &\dots & a_{nn}\\
\end{bmatrix}

\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 & \dots & 0 \\
a_{21} & a_{22} &\dots & a_{2n}\\
\dots \\
a_{n1} & a_{n2} &\dots & a_{nn}\\
\end{bmatrix}
For example the above two matrices are $A_1$ and $A_2$, respectively.

And we see that $A_1,\dots,A_n$ do not depend on $a_{11},\dots,a_{1n}$, i.e. elements of $1$st row of matrix $A$. Could I conclude that $f(A_1),\dots, f(A_n)$ also do not depends on elements of $1$st row of $A$. If yes, how one can show it rigorously?

Intuitively I know that this is correct statement but cannot prove it rigorously.
Would be very grateful for help!

Comment: Doesn't $A_2$ depend on row $2$ of matrix $A$?

Comment: @Minus One-Twelfth, edited!

Comment: It is not clear what you mean. You can consider $A_k$ to be a function of $a_{ik}$ with $i \ge 2$.

Comment: To elaborate, define $A_1:\mathbb{R}^{n \times n} \to \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ to be the first matrix above. Then $A_1(A+t E_{1j}) = A_1(A)$ for all $t$ (and $j$). So we can interpret $A_1$ as being defined on the quotient $\mathbb{R}^{n \times n} / \operatorname{sp} \{ E_{1,j} \}_j$.